# How to get default selected customer shipping address?

Tags: customer, address, default

```
if (is_null($this->_address)) {
    if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    } else {
    $ship = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
    $ship_country = $ship->getCountryId();
    if(!empty($ship_country))
        $this->_address = $ship;
    else
        $this->_address = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address');
    }
}
```

Please reply if you have any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
/**
 * Get logged in customer
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    if (empty($this->_customer)) {
        $this->_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    }
    return $this->_customer;
}

public function getAddress()
{
    if (is_null($this->_address)) {
        if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            if(!$this->_address) {
                $this->_address = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            }
        } else {
            $ship = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            $ship_country = $ship->getCountryId();
            if(!empty($ship_country)) {
                $this->_address = $ship;
            } else {
                $this->_address = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **thanks for the reply.**

We need only default selected shipping address in ALT DELIVERY ADDRESS drop down in one-page checkout.

Comment: $this->_address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryShippingAddress(); -> return default shipping address.

Comment: sohel => This is not working for getting default address in ALT DELIVERY ADDRESS.